# automaticallyConfigureSession is Deprecated?

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

I am using RealityKit in Xcode, and for some reason, when I type `arView.automaticallyConfigureSession`,xcode tells me it doesn't exist. I check on the apple developer site, and it says that it exists (it doesn't have the deprecated label under it). I am not sure what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select a physical device instead of a simulator.

Once you select the physical device, hit <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to build the app and the error should go a way